# Android TranslateAnimation Processes Stuff After Animation During Animation

Tags: android, animation, android-relativelayout, android-animation

I'm trying to slide in a view on a RelativeLayout via an animation.  Once the view is in place I have to alter the layout params of layout so that the new view doesn't block existing content.  I call the code to update the layout after the animation but it occurs before the animation causing a block of area to be blank during the animation.

The following screens are before animation, during and after:

[image: animation]

Here is the code.  The relative layout is adjusted in onShowAd.

```
        float fromY = getAdHeight();
        float toY = 0;
        TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,fromY,toY);
        slide.setDuration(ANIMATION_RATE);
        slide.setFillAfter(true);
        mAdLayout.startAnimation(slide);
        onShowAd();
        mAdLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I tried differing orders of calling visible and other things as well as using a handler to postDelayed onShowAd() to wait the same amount of time as the ANIMATION_RATE however what happened you'd stare at the black box for the time it was post delayed and then have to wait for the animation so it was worse.  In windows there's an API call LOCKWINDOWUPDATE that I could pass in a window handle to prevent updating...is there anything equivalent for a view in Android?  Or any other ideas?

Incidentally when sliding the view OUT it works fine.  Here is the code going the other way.  onHideAd is where the layoutparams are modified in this one.

```
        float toY = ((View) mAdLayout.getParent()).getBottom();
        float fromY = 0;//toY - mAdLayout.getHeight();
        TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,fromY,toY);
        slide.setDuration(ANIMATION_RATE);
        slide.setFillAfter(true);           
        mAdLayout.startAnimation(slide); 
        mAdLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        onHideAd();
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT: I added the listener and that doesn't take care of it.  I have isolated it to the following code which in in the "onShowAd()" routine:

```
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mainFragmentContainer.getLayoutParams();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, mAdLayout.getId());
        mainFragmentContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I've tried to further separate it by calling it with a handler.postDelayed and it seems like anywhere I place it in the chain of events causes it to occur BEFORE the animation itself shows.  Very odd! :-(

This is the updated showAd routine.  I tried reordering some of the calls as well.

```
        float fromY = getAdHeight();
        float toY = 0;
        TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,fromY,toY);
        slide.setDuration(ANIMATION_RATE);
        slide.setFillAfter(true);
        slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override 
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override 
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                onShowAd();
            }
        });
        mAdLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAdLayout.startAnimation(slide);
```

Comment: Maybe you should try calling ``onShowAd()`` from Animation.AnimationListener.onAnimationEnd?

Comment: Good idea, but doesn't work.  The original example I based this on was using a linear layout.  Is it perhaps just not suitable for a relative layout?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) to accomplish what you are looking for. The problem you are running into is caused because the call to start animation returns instantly even though the animation doesn't complete for the time set to ANIMATION_RATE.

Ex for slide in:

```
    float fromY = getAdHeight();
    float toY = 0;
    TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,fromY,toY);
    slide.setDuration(ANIMATION_RATE);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);     
    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }           
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {                
        }           
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
             onShowAd();
        }
    });
    mAdLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mAdLayout.startAnimation(slide);
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense but no joy :-(  Same exact behavior.